# Display rowcount beside each filter at grid

Tags: ag-grid

I am using AG grid enterprise to display my data. I have filters for each columns. I want to show the count of each filter element inside the filter drop-down itself. Please help. It's like if the filter shows that we have only us and Canada  in the country column, I want to display the frequencies of us and canada inside parenthesis beside these filter elements

Answer (score 0):

> Update: added working sample

```
filterParams: { cellRenderer: "countryFilterRenderer"}

countryFilterRenderer(params) {
  let count = this.rowData.filter(i=>i.country.name==params.value).length;
  return `${params.value}(${count})`;
}

rowData:[{country:{name:..., code:...}];
```

`rowData` definition just for clarity.

For more info check [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/) with samples, and official [demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/) with [sources](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.js).

> Update: added hot data sample

Once we need to have data - related from `sorting` or `filtering` we [can use API methods](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#accessing-row-nodes): `forEachNodeAfterFilter`, `forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort`, `getDisplayedRowCount`.

```
sportFilterRenderer(params){
    let count;
    if(this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() != this.rowData.length){
      count = 0;
      this.gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node=>{
        if(node.data.sport == params.value)
          count++;
      })
    }
    else{
        count = this.rowData.filter(i=>i.sport==params.value).length;
    }
    return `${params.value}(${count})`;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bCI0SJ (check country and sport filters)

On sample `plnkr` count in `sport` filter would be recalculated every time once you will select\deselect anything from `country` filter

> Update: hot changes handling via `cellRenderer`

So `ag-grid` team noticed about this issues and they have it on `backlock` - before this - there is no way to handle your requirement in the same way as we tried. [Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/) you can find an issue (AG-2078)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Say, I have two columns, country and city. When I click on filter button, it should show US(20) and UK(10) in country column. How am I getting hold of counting the frequency of each type of data? Is there a looping mechanism or something?

Comment: 'when I click on filter button' on a filter of which column. Provide a sample data or fiddler and I will try to help.

Comment: Filter of country column I meant. My grid has two columns, country and city. I am using AG grid enterprise. A row will be having a country and city name. When I click on filter button of the country column, the filter values (each individual country name) should contain the value how many occurance of that country is there in the grid.

Comment: I want something like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40865679/ag-grid-count-the-number-of-rows-for-each-filter-choice

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Sorry, I am a rookie into AG grid.

Comment: I have another doubt. If I have two columns with aggregate data in the filter (like the country column in the example above), after I filter one of the columns, the aggregate data doesn't get refreshed in another column. Any idea how to refresh aggregate data each time a column is filtered?

Comment: create a new question, to avoid overextend working sample and please provide your code.

Comment: It's the same code that you have provided in plunker. I just added one more column with aggregate data. Once I filter one of the two columns, the other column aggregate data doesn't get updated.

Comment: Not get what you mean and what you wanna to achieve

Comment: I will explain. Say my grid has two columns, city and country. Both shows count data along with filter choices as your code does for country column. Now, say, I apply filter on country column to filter out two countries. Naturally, the city column filter count data should change right? (As there are two countries which are filtered out). This is not happening. It's like we should refresh the grid every time the filter is changed, along with the filter count data. Does it make sense now?

Comment: >Naturally, the city column filter count data should change right? 
based on sample `rowData` represent only initial data, so if you need `hot` data - it should be handled on different way

Comment: That does, thank u so much. Just a small glitch. Once I deselect a filter element, the count beside it doesn't become 0 on deselection. To reflect the value 0, first I have to come out of filter, press on the filter button again to see that the count of deselected choice has become 0. Any suggestions so that the value 0 gets reflected immediately after deselect?

Comment: So, seems like its possible only via own `FilterComponent` cuz you will be able to handle `filterChangedCallback` and `filterModifiedCallback` directly inside component and modify the result on a needed format.

Comment: If possible, could you please provide a small example? Sorry to bother you with this, but as I mentioned, I am very new to this and learnt so much from you. Again, no pressure.

Comment: got info from devs - check post.